# How to update only images and text without having to override the whole solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, image-management

I have a very small e-commerce website(not launched yet). Requirement: users need to be able to change image and text content only (not the price). Images and text are saved in a folder at the server (no database for images). Based on my research, I still have not got better idea than possibly creating a WCF Restful service!! My Code are in GitHub and project is hosted in Azure. I am using ASP.Net, MVC-5, RESTful, OData. 
*Please suggest me possible best approaches with reasons, if you could.*

Comment: I am a beginner, and I definitely did the research. I would appreciate just a few line of expert suggestions/direction. No comments on negative vote!!

Answer (score 0):

Images and such are considered a BLOBs (Binary Large Object). Best practice for storing those on Azure is to use Blob Storage.

You can find step-by-step tutorial here:
[How to use Blob storage from .NET](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/)

Next time when you deploy your solution, it will not override images and texts, since those will not be in solution folder.

Comment: Awesome. Something to start with. Thank you much.